# Forge Viewer: changing fragment material

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is there a way to change the material of an existing fragment? I see there is a [changing fragment material](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Extensions/ModelBuilder/#changefragmentmaterial-fragment-material) function in the documentation, but this seems to be for adding custom models, rather than manipulating existing fragments in the viewer.

I specifically wish to change the material so I can manipulate the linewidth of the fragment. I've tried manipulating the `fragments` of `viewer.model.getFragmentList()`, specifically `Viewer.model.getFragmentList().getMaterial(i)` and its properties (such as `linewidth`) to no avail, even after updating via `viewer.impl.invalidate`

Answer (score 0):

While this is not part of the officially supported Viewer APIs, you *can* change the material of existing fragments using the fragment list's `setMaterial` method, for example like so:

```js
function changeSelectedObjects(viewer, customMaterial) {
    const materialManager = viewer.impl.matman();
    materialManager.addMaterial('myCustomMaterial', customMaterial, true /* skip material heuristics */);
    const model = viewer.model;
    model.unconsolidate(); // If the model is consolidated, material changes won't have any effect
    const tree = model.getInstanceTree();
    const frags = model.getFragmentList();
    const dbids = viewer.getSelection();
    for (const dbid of dbids) {
        tree.enumNodeFragments(dbid, (fragid) => {
            frags.setMaterial(fragid, customMaterial);
        });
    }
}
```

See https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-shader-materials-forge-viewer for a more specific example.

With that said, changing the line width might be trickier, especially if it's about modifying 2D drawings. I don't think that kind of customization has been explored very well.